# Linux wc command & file descriptor

Tags: linux, terminal

in linux terminal,

```
$ echo hi > foo
$ wc foo > foo
$ cat foo
0 0 0 foo (Output)
$
```

But if

```
$ echo hi >foo
$ wc foo
1 1 3 foo (Output)
$
```

Why these outputs are different?

Comment: Because `>` truncates the file before anything else happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect output to a file, the file is first emptied. So the file doesn't contain anything in it when `wc` tries to read it.

In general, you shouldn't try to use the same file as input and output, it will almost never work.

Answer (score 1):

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said in his answer the ' > ' Symbol empties the file before writing the new data to the file to which output is being redirected. so what you are essentially doing is using **wc** on an emptied file.

Instead of truncating the output you can append (' >> ') the output using the following code :

```
$ wc foo >> foo
$ cat foo
hi
1 1 3 foo
```

To get a more deep understanding on I/O Redirection in Linux follow the following article which covers the topic in detail.

[An Introduction to Linux I/O Redirection](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection)

Comment: Thanks it's working for me...